# Why Set is allowing duplicate Byte Integer and Long values

Tags: java, set

As my knowledge set basically have two methods equals() and hashcode(),based on which its determining the values contains are equal and avoiding duplicate entry,but below program where i get confused,even wrapper classes also have both methods overridden then why its accepting duplicate values?

**Code:**

```
Collection col=new LinkedHashSet();
col.add(new Long(65));
col.add(new Byte((byte) 65));
col.add(new Integer(65));
col.add("A");

System.out.println(col);
```

Answer: [65,65,65,A]
But I expected [65,A]

Answer (score 7):

A `Long` instance can never be equal to an `Integer` instance which can never be equal to a `Byte` instance, even if both have the same numeric value. The 3 instances you put in your `Set` are not equal to each other.

See, for example, `Integer`'s `equals` :

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Integer) {
        return value == ((Integer)obj).intValue();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Both instances must be of the same type in order to be equal to each other (a necessary condition).

Comment: Long l=new Long(65);
  System.out.println(l);
  Integer it=new Integer(65);
  System.out.println(it);
  System.out.println(l.equals(it));

Answer (score 2):

Here is what the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) for `Integer.equals(Object)` says:

> Compares this object to the specified object. The result is true *if and only if* the argument is not `null` **and is an `Integer` object** that contains the same int value as this object.

In other words, an `Integer` object cannot be equal to an object that is not also an `Integer` object.  The same applies to all of the primitive wrapper classes.

Thus, those 4 objects in your example are not equal, and hence not duplicates, according to the semantics of `HashSet`.

---

Unfortunately, if you are using `HashSet` or any other of the standard Java hashtable-based classes, together with the standard wrapper classes, there is no workaround for this.

However:

- If you were to use `TreeSet` or similar, you could work around this issue using a custom `Comparator` object.
- There is an alternative hash table implementation in Guava that allows you to supply external equals and hashCode implementations.
- You could create your own wrapper classes with different semantics for equals and hashcode to the standard classes.  Unfortunately, these would not interoperate with other things; e.g. Java auto-boxing / auto-unboxing.

Answer (score 1):

Set does not allow duplicate values. The question here is what is duplicate and what is not.

Duplicate values are those thatare of the same type, have the same hashCode() and also return `true` when being compared. Objects of different types (in your case Byte and Long) are not equal in these terms.

If you want however to put values of different numeric types into Set and enjoy cross-type behavior, you can use `TreeSet` with your custom `Comparator` that  compares *values* only without taking the type into consideration.

Comment: Let me be nitpicking (sorry): "Duplicate values are those that are of the same type [...]" => Although it should be true, it is completely up to the _equals_ implementation and not a characteristic of a collection. As it stands, this sentence is somewhat misleading, isn't it?

Comment: You are right, it is up to equals implementation. However OP plays with primitive wrappers that already have their implementations of equals.